# Safe usage of Perl's magic diamond

Tags: perl

B::Lint doesn't like `while (<>) {do stuff}`, docs show nasty injection attack due to its internal use of the evil 2 argument open.  Is there an easy way to make this usage safer?  I have a lot of minor scripts that use this.

Comment: Scripts on a web facing server or NATed and firewalled dev box??

Comment: The latter.  But I like to assume a dangerous environment

Comment: Then it depends on the script usage and which user has access to it.  If the user has access to /bin then he has much more powerful tools to root your box with.

Comment: In my day to day scripting I use <> with abandon but I have some cron jobs ( which run under different permissions ) where I was much more careful in taint checks and I/O attack proofing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ARGV::readonly.](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ARGV::readonly) It will allow for safer usage of the diamond operator.

> ARGV::readonly - make <> open files regardless of leading/trailing whitespace and/or control characters such as |, >, amd <.

Answer (score 1):

The magic diamond is there for your convenience. Getc(), read(), readline(), and sysread() are all available and each offers a different tradeoff of security vs. convenience.